# VS Code extension logo

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have just installed VS Code and the extensions logo does not look right. In the pictures shown in VS Code site or in YouTube tutorials it looks like 4 squares surrounded with another square that are hold together tight. Mine there are three squares and the fourth one is tilted away as if the extension icon is broken. Is there anything wrong with my installation?

Comment: Maybe the icon has changed - does the extension functionality *work*? Has anything other than the appearance made you think there's a problem?

Comment: they changed the style of icons around v1.37. Updating the documentation will be a big job so they don't do it if the picture is very simular.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers (and I am so sorry for my late response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Extensions icon in VS Code looks the same as you just described. The icon must have changed since the image that you are referencing.

[image: VS Code Extension Panel]

I think your installation is just fine. No reason to worry about this issue, at least.

Comment: thank you very much jwDavis. This solves it for me. Yeah everything seems to work fine but I was worried that I was missing on something.

Comment: I am happy to have helped.